# Android: Intent setup for implementing application lock screen

Tags: android, android-intent, password-protection

I have a password lock in my app. The user can save a password in the settings, and choose to only allow a user into the application with a password. When the app starts, the user is presented with a splash screen. In this Activity, if the user has chosen to enable password lock in the settings, I present a dialog that asks for the password.

To make sure that the user who wants the app locked is presented with this screen every time they try to use the app, I have set:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

in the Manifest for this Activity, which is the launch/main activity of my app. What sucks about this is that it does not let other users multitask (users who haven't chosen to lock the app) away, and come back where they left off. IF and only if they have come into the app through this activity. If, however, they come into the app through a different Activity (I have a widget that broadcasts a few different Intents), then the user can multitask, and come back into the app where they left off (until they actually back all the way out of the app using the back button).

Is there a way to get both sets of functionality here? Can I have the app always open to the password lock splash screen for users who want password lock, and have good ol' multitasking without messing with how the app loads for the other users?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `clearTaskOnLaunch`, you could put a conditional statement in the 'onStart' of every Activity that you have.

Example:

```
if (pref.getBoolean("requiresPassword", false)){
    startActivity(new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class));
}
```

In order to make the code more portable and easier to place in every Activity, I create one single class that contains several methods, so for example:

```
public class M {
   public static void check(final Context context){
       //do the shared prefs getting and startActivity from here.
   }
}
```

And then in your `onStart` for every `Activity`, all you'd have to do is `M.check(this);`

**EDIT:**

As Scienceprodigy, the above would cause an infinte loop. I didn't think of that.

What I would actually do is create a Dialog popup asking for the password like this:

```
public static void requestPassword(final Context context){
        final SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final Activity activity = (Activity)context;
        boolean requestPassword = pref.getBoolean("appLock", false);
//      Log.i(tag, String.valueOf(requestPassword));
        if (!requestPassword){
            return;
        }

        final EditText myPass2 = new EditText(context);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Enter Password")
            .setView(myPass2)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    String secPass = pref.getString("secPassword", "password");
                    String entPass = myPass2.getText().toString();
                    if (entPass.equals(secPass)){
                        myPass2.setText("");
                        saveTime(context);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText((Activity)context, "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        myPass2.setText("");
                        activity.finish();
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    myPass2.setText("");
                    activity.finish();
                }
            })
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    myPass2.setText("");
                    activity.finish();
                }
            })
            .show();
        }
```

Comment: This will create an infinite loop of password checking, entering the password, then password checking, etc.

Comment: @Scienceprodigy I updated my answer to use an AlertDialog instead of launching the splash screen. This may not be exactly what you are wanting, but from a user perspective, if trying to multi-task, I would prefer a dialog. It seems easier. Of course, you could use a custom layout defined in XML if that suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

1. Subclass your activity class so you have 2 empty inner classes:

   ```
   public class MyActivity {

       public static class Locked extends MyActivity {
       }

       public static class NoLock extends MyActivity {
       }

       // ...

   }
   ```
2. Modify the manifest to point to the inner classes, one with `clearTaskOnLaunch` flag set to true and another set to false:

   ```
   <!-- original activity -->
   <activity android:name="MyActivity$Locked"
       android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" >
       <!-- other flags and elements ... -->
   </activity>

   <!-- unlocked activity -->
   <activity android:name="MyActivity$NoLock"
       android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false" >
       <!-- other flags and elements ... -->
   </activity>
   ```
3. Modify your widget code to launch either the `MyActivity.Locked` or `MyActivity.NoLock` based on whether the user has enabled the application password lock or not.
4. If the activity is previously launched from the Launcher (has `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in its manifest entry), you might need to create a simple "welcome" activity to replace it which will need to decide which version of MyActivity to start in the `onCreate()` method, something like:

   ```
   public class Welcome extends Activity {

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
           super.onCreate(icicle);

           if (mPasswordLocked) {
               startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.Locked.class));
           } else {
               startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.NoLock.class));
           }

           finish();
       }


   }
   ```

Comment: This looks like a promising solution, but how will it solve launching the app from Home?

Comment: Added step #4 to address the Launcher activity.